# Is there a framework/library to easily manage databases on Android aside from SQLiteOpenHelper?

Tags: android, orm

I have only used SQLiteOpenHelper and it's not that easy to use.

I wonder if there's an ORM similar to Django or Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like Django, have a look at http://www.androrm.com. The query syntax is very similar to that of Django including the table_*table*_table query mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this helps but [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) supports Android native database calls and provides sub classes of `SQLiteOpenHelper` to provide mature ORM features.  I am the main author.  There is a good set of Android developers which are using it successfully for their applications.

> http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml

I'm not sure how it compares with Django ar Rails.  It is designed to be a lightweight replacement for Hibernate or iBatis while still providing good ORM functionality.  We have some example Android applications to see how it works.

> http://ormlite.com/docs/android-examples

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for a really simple to implement library have a look at this.

```
http://www.rushorm.com/
```

Written with ease of use as the first priority. Handles many to many relationships and saving children which most others don't seem to.